# How to loop through a txt file against a csv file

Tags: awk, grep

I have 2 files, the first one:

values.txt

```
test@gmail.com
test1@gmail.com
test3@gmail.com
test4@gmail.com
test5@gmail.com
test6@gmail.com
test7@gmail.com
test8@gmail.com
test9@gmail.com
test10@gmail.com
```

data.csv

```
"username","email"
"user","test@gmail.com"
"user1","test1@gmail.com"
"user2","test3@gmail.com"
"user4","test4@gmail.com"
"user456","loka@gmail.com"
"user789","lopa@gmail.com"
"user5","test7@gmail.com"
"user","xpos@gmail.com"
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
"user","xpx@gmail.com"
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
"user","test@gmail.com"
"user1","test1@gmail.com"
"user2","test3@gmail.com"
"user4","test4@gmail.com"
"user5","test7@gmail.com"
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
```

What I was able to do :

```
awk -F',' '$2 ~ /test9@gmail.com/ {print $0}' data.csv > test1.csv
```

This will create a new file test1.csv containing:

```
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
```

Couldn't figure out how to loop through the file and exchange the `test9@gmail.com` with the line of the values.txt

Comment: Cross-posted at Unix&Linux (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/632313) and AskUbuntu (https://askubuntu.com/q/1313072).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F, -v q='"' 'NR==FNR{a[q $0 q]; next} 
                    FNR==1 || $2 in a' values data

"username","email"
"user","test@gmail.com"
"user1","test1@gmail.com"
"user2","test3@gmail.com"
"user4","test4@gmail.com"
"user5","test7@gmail.com"
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
```

to print without the header, just remove `FNR==1 ||`

Comment: Thank you for you response, Unfortunately nothing is happening when tried it, is it possible to save it in a new csv file ?

Comment: just redirect the output with  `> outputfile`

Comment: Unfortunately a empty file. I'll work on it thank you

Comment: make sure you write the filename as you named them with the suffixes.  I used placeholder names.

Comment: I did it's returning me only the header

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data following `grep` should also work:

```sh
grep -Fwf values.txt data.csv

"user","test@gmail.com"
"user1","test1@gmail.com"
"user2","test3@gmail.com"
"user4","test4@gmail.com"
"user5","test7@gmail.com"
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, so I tried it and unfortunately I'm getting all the initial file without the sort.

Comment: Most likely you have DOS line breaks in your file. Run `dos2unix` before running this `grep`

Answer (score 0):

if you can't pre-assume files were sorted at all, try

```
    gawk -b -e 'BEGIN { 
   
        CONST_DBLQUOTE = sprintf("%c", 34)       # safe double quote, 
                                                 # maybe too cautious

        FILENAME = ARGV[ ARGC – 2 ]              # always the item
                                                 # prior to last in
                                                 # arguments in 0-based 
                                                 # index, by design

        FS = "^$";                               # don't waste time                                                                                                                                 
                                                 # trying to split fields
        while (getline) { valuesL[$0]++ } 
        nextfile
        
        FS = CONST_DBLQUOTE
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"   # perform auto-sorting

    } (NF==1) || ($(NF-1) in valuesL) {

        inputL[NR] = $0 

    } END { for (line in inputL) { print line } }' values.txt data.csv
```

I think this should handle it just fine, unicode or not. If you know the file is pre-sorted, and have a VERY large input data set to work with, run it with mawk1.9.9.6 instead.